# string formatting, remove leading chars

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this: 00:11:40 or 00:02:40 how do I formated so that I can always get rid of the leading zero(s) and colon(s), so it looks like this 
11:40 or 2:40

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We call these "leading" characters, not trailing, since they're at the beginning, but the regex for this is very easy

```
x.sub(/^[0:]*/,"")
```

That works exactly as you phrased it: starting at the beginning of the string, remove all the 0s and :s.

Comment: Some of us are just humble students of the regex, others are just masters (you got an up from me). That's what happens when you TDD at 2200 hrs. Refactoring is left as an exercise.

Comment: `"00:00:23"` results in `"23"` which seems odd. But no offense, this is still exactly what the OP requested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like Peter said, but would correctly be:

```
s = "00:11:40"
s = s[3..-1]   # 11:40
```

Another approach would be to use the split method:

```
s = "00:11:40".split(":")[1,2].join(":")
```

Although I find that one more confusing and complex.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the OP wanted this from the beginning:

```
seconds = 11*60+40
Time.at(seconds.to_i).gmtime.strftime('%M:%S')  # gives '11:40'
```

or see `man strftime` for more formatting options.

EDIT: incorporating all the discussion, here's the recommended approach. It removes the need for the Time call as well.

```
seconds = seconds.to_i
if seconds >= 60
  "#{seconds/60}:#{seconds%60}"
else
  "#{seconds}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need a general way of doing this. I get the string through a conversion from seconds Time.at(seconds.to_i).gmtime.strftime('%R:%S')

Comment: Close! I need to figure how to use "gsub" with some regex to strip the leading zeros and/or colons

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try positive look-behind regex.
Nice [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
it "should look-behind for zeros" do
time = remove_behind_zeroes("ta:da:na")
time.should be_nil

time = remove_behind_zeroes("22:43:20")
time.should == "22:43:20"

time = remove_behind_zeroes("00:12:30")
time.should == "12:30"

time = remove_behind_zeroes("00:11:40")
time.should == "11:40"

time = remove_behind_zeroes("00:02:40")
time.should == "2:40"

time = remove_behind_zeroes("00:00:26")
time.should == "26"
```

end

```
def remove_behind_zeroes(value)
exp = /(?<=00:00:)\d\d/
match = exp.match(value)
if match then return match[0] end

exp = /(?<=00:0)\d:\d\d/
match = exp.match(value)
if match then return match[0] end

exp = /(?<=00:)\d\d:\d\d/
match = exp.match(value)
if match then return match[0] end

exp = /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/
match = exp.match(value)
if match then return match[0] end
nil
```

end

Comment: No need for four different regexes and 15 lines of code to do this! A single .sub(/^[0:]*/,"") works fine!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the times you can simply rely on basic conversion techniques, in ruby for example, if you had a string like "05" and wanted it to just be 5, you'd simply do "05".to_i